# How to do a one-liner while loop in Ruby using curly braces

Tags: ruby

I was trying to do a simple one liner while loop in ruby using the curly braces. I was sucessful in the following formats:

```
while x < 5 do x+=1 end
```

This is sufficient as a one liner but im not a fan of using do end in one liners. I would like to do something similar to this:

```
while x < 5 { x += 1 }
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I am assuming this is over simplified for the means of this question but I do not believe keywords like `while`, `for`, etc. accept block syntax. That being said using `Enumerable` methods do so something like `(x...5).each { x += 1}` will offer the same result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this one:

```
x = 0
x += 1 while x < 5
x 
#=> 5
```

Comment: That reads really well.  `x += 1 until x == 5` is another option. I prefer `while`, but `until` deserves mention.

Answer (score 8):

If the question is "How to use `while` with curly braces? Can it be done?", then the answer is: *No, it is not possible*.

Instead, you could use **while** without do...end, and **without curly braces**:

```
x = 0
(x+=1; p x) while x<5
```

**Or** you could use **curly braces without while**, to achieve the same:

```
x=0
(x+1..5).each{|y| p y}
```

Comment: Though, these two are different, as in they handle different scoping rules. Variables created inside a `while loop` will be visible to outer scopes. The same does not applies for, say  `each` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
x = 0
while x < 5 do
  puts x
  x += 1
end
```

you could write this:

```
5.times { |i| puts i }
```